# Version control personally and simply?

Tags: version-control, file-management

Requirement

1. make history for web text/code source files.
2. login-worker is only me, i.e personal usage.
3. automatically save history for each updated files(no require at once but at least once per week)
4. It must be a simple way to start and work.
5. I have 3 work places so need to do async files.
6. (not must but hopefully for future working environment) Any other non-engineer can also understand the location of history file and can see it easily.

Current way:
I made history folder the day, download files in there for edit, copy files when I edit/creat new one.

Advantage of the current way:
 Very quick and simple, no need to do additional task to make history

Disadvantage of the current way:
 Messy. Whenever day I work, I create a new history folder to keep downloaded files, so that it is messy in Finder(or windows explore).
 Also, I don't have a way to Doing Async files for sure with in other places.

I tested to use GIT before, I had Thought GIT automatically save files I edit and save with a editor, but that was not the case. Also GIT is too complicated to use/start. If you recommend GIT, you need to show me ways to deal with the problem I had, for instance, simple GIT GUI with limited options without merging/project/branch etc because of personal usage for maintaining just one website.

Do you know any way to do version control personally and simply?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you entered `<form ...>` in your HTML—without the closing tag—and saved the file; do you really think the commit created by our imaginary VCS picked up that file's update event would have any sense?

What I mean, is that as with writing programs¹,
the history of source code changes are there *for humans to read,*
and for that matter, a good history graph should really read like a prose:
each commit should be atomic in the sense it comprises one (small) but
internally integral feature or fixes a bug, and had to be properly annotated
so that *the intent* of the change captured by that commit is clear.

What you want instead is just some dumb stream of changes purely for backup purposes.

Well, if you're fully aware of the repercussions (the most glaring one is that the generated history is completely useless for doing *development* on
the project and can only be used for rollbacks in case of "oopsies"),
there are two ways to go:

- Some IDEs (namely, Eclipse) save a backup copy of each file they manage
  on each save—thus providing your with such a rollback functionality w/o
  using any VCS.
- Script around any VCS you like: say, on Linux,
  you start something like [`inotifywait`](https://manpages.debian.org/inotifywait) telling it to watch your
  project's root directory, recurvively, for `write` events on files,
  read whatever the tool prints to its `stdout` when these events happen,
  and for each event, call to your VCS of choice to record a new commit
  with these changes.

---

¹ «Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.» — Abelson & Sussman, "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs", preface to the first edition.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly suggest you to have a deeper look at git.

It may looks difficult at the beginning, but you should spend some time learning it, that's all. All the problems above could be easily solved if you spend some time to learn the basics. There is also a nice "tutorial" on github on how to use git, no need to install anything: https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1.

Comment: Matteo A:As described above, one of my big concern is having additional operation with using GIT, i,e. push or commit operation after I made some html file with a editor.

Comment: You already do "additional operation" after you write some code. Now you copy paste some folder, zip it, rename it...you can (but shouldn't) see like this: you do everything you do normally, but instead at the end of the day you do a "git commit" and a "git push". You decide when to commit or push something, it's up to you. Start with a single branch to get used to it. Try the mentioned tutorial...

Comment: You already do "additional operation" after you write some code :Nop! I download file from server to a History Folder before edit. I copy the file to Working folder. Then I edit the file and save it. Then I upload the file to the server. That's all.

Comment: By the way, for short time version controlling, using editors(or application's) history tool works fine. So I don't need another tools to go back to a history of a file on that I worked same day same place.

Comment: Well, so you do additional operation after AND before coding! Wouldn't be much better to just enter two commands in the command line (or use you editor/IDE that for sure has a git integration)? Again, it's just a matter of you taking the time to learn git (or another versioning tool, but the learning curve is quite the same)

Comment: Apparently it Wouldn't be better to just enter  Additional two commands in the command line every time I work, plus I (and future successors) have to spend time to be expert of GIT command operation.